# Session wide filtering of querysets in Django admin for super user

Tags: python, django, django-admin, multi-tenant

I can't really find any good answers to my problem.

I have several organisations in my Django application. I do admin work in the Django admin.
It use autocomplete on most of my foreign key fields.

It gets tedious to find the correct objects that belong to the correct organisations in the list.
So I would like to have results filtered in autocomplete fields to the organisation the object belongs to.

But since I choose organisation for an object when I create it the chosen object is not available on the server yet since it is not saved. There seems to be some hacks around there to get the value of the chosen field from the DOM and then do it all in Javascript.
But that seems like a lot of work to maintain.

What would be better for me is if I could choose which organisation I am currently working on.
Then I would want the organisation field in forms to be prefilled and read-only to that organisation and all foreign keys field to be filtered for results to just the current organisation.

What is the simplest way of implementing this. I have not found anything in the django admin docs that seems like it could be used.

What I'm thinking to do is to override the django admin template and add an autocomplete field in the menu header with current organisation and add a cookie with the uuid of the organisation. Then I should be able to override all functionality I need by accessing this cookie in the request and use the id to filter the querysets.

Does anyone know a simpler solution?

Comment: It all boils down to you making `ajax` requests using javascript if you want to make dependent dropdowns (even in django-admin, as the page is client side the server cannot know what the user is doing on the page unless they make a request). Don't know how a cookie can help you here in any way. So no, you need to use javascript.

Comment: OK. I am fine with at any current moment all my foreign keys / models are filtered against the same organisation.
Pretty much as I would be a user of the organization and would only be allowed access to my own organizations data.
It would be simillar to a "work as user" function, just that I don't have any users to access the admin as of now.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a pragmatic solution.

Via admin actions on the Organization model I can set the current active organization.

```py
def set_current_organisation(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    org = queryset.first()
    if org:
        request.session["admin_current_organization"] = {
            "id": str(org.id),
            "name": org.name,
        }


set_current_organisation.short_description = "Set organization as current organization"


def clear_current_organisation(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    del request.session["admin_current_organization"]


clear_current_organisation.short_description = "Clear current organization choice"
```

Then I create a base ModelAdmin for all the models that need to be filtered against organization:

```py
class CurrentOrganizationDependantModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    A ModelAdmin override to make all organization bound models in admin locked
    to the current active organization in the admin.
    The current active organization is set in the
    request.session[""admin_current_organization""]
    It is also necessary the all ForeignKey field are autocomplete fields.
    """

    def get_list_filter(self, request):
        """
        If an current organization is set we exclude the list filter for organizations
        """
        current_admin_org = request.session.get("admin_current_organization")
        if current_admin_org is not None:
            new_list_filter = []
            for old_filter in super().get_list_filter(request):
                if not old_filter.startswith("organization"):
                    new_list_filter.append(old_filter)
            return tuple(new_list_filter)
        else:
            return super().get_list_filter(request)

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        """
        If a current organization is set we set it as default on new objects.
        """
        current_admin_org = request.session.get("admin_current_organization")
        initial_data = super().get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        if current_admin_org is not None:
            initial_data["organization"] = uuid.UUID(current_admin_org["id"])

        return initial_data

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Exclude objects not belonging to model in many to many
        """
        db = kwargs.get("using")
        if "queryset" not in kwargs:
            queryset = self.get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
            if queryset is not None:
                kwargs["queryset"] = queryset

        current_admin_org = request.session.get("admin_current_organization")

        if current_admin_org:
            qs = kwargs.get("queryset")
            if qs:
                qs = qs.filter(organization__id=uuid.UUID(current_admin_org["id"]))
                kwargs["queryset"] = qs
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        """
        Will filter the whole list result set to the current active organization.
        it will also filter autocomplete fields.
        """
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(
            request, queryset, search_term
        )
        current_admin_org = request.session.get("admin_current_organization")

        if current_admin_org:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                organization__id=uuid.UUID(current_admin_org["id"])
            )

        return queryset, use_distinct
```

I also overrode the base admin template to show the name of the current active organization in the top menu by accessing the session data.